# Handle different google maps center depending on media query

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, responsiveness

This is probably really simple to do, I am just not sure how to handle it currently. I am building a site using Foundation 5 as responsive framework and in the footer section there's a map. In the tablet and desktop versions the contact form is positioned over the map with the map visible on both sides of the form element. The mobile version has the map first and the contact form afterwards. To put it graphically it's something like that.

**Tablet/Desktop Version**

[image: Tablet/Desktop Version]

**Mobile Version**

[image: Mobile Version]

So, now, in terms of responsiveness what I would normally do to keep the map centered is use:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
});
```

Now that would work OK if the map's center was actually the map's center, but as you can see in the examples, the map center in the Tablet/Desktop version is a little to the East of the Marker and in the Mobile Version the Center and the Marker share position.

Is there any way to use the resize event listener with different coordinates depending on media query or window size?

Comment: do form and map have a fixed size(depending on the media-query?)

Comment: @Dr.Molle they only have fixed height, the width varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matchMedia` to determine each case:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  var latLng;
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(bigLat,bigLng);
  } else {
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(smallLat,smallLng);
  }
  map.setCenter(latLng);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Also, `resize` is one of those events that can fire VERY rapidly. You may want to consider throttling that event: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: That worked :) You just mixed up the variable in the `setCenter`, `lagLng` instead of `latLng` but worked perfectly :) Just changed the min-width

Comment: Wrote the comment after I saw I could edit it :) Sorry

Comment: Oh, yeah I remembered it asked me for the edit to be at least 6 characters or something like that, didn't see the other error. Thanks for the answer again!